# How to add code coverage metrics to a PR?

Tags: github, code-coverage

I am going to add code coverage to a repo, so when a PR is created the CI is going to generate code coverage reports with lcov.

What is the best way to show this metric in a PR to the dev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to make a python script to:
1- Look for packages with tests.
2- For each language have a different strategy (I had Python 2, Python 3 and C++ tests in the same repository).
3- Combine all the coverage results in one folder.
4- With regex look for the coverage percentages.
5- Build a nice table with the data and show it via a PR comment.

Graphs and more fancy output can also be done after the regex step.